# Wordpress the_meta and get_post_meta- Hide empty values in custom fields

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hide the display of custom fields if they have no values.  If I display them with **the_meta**, then the headers show, whether or not there are any values in the Custom Fields.

It generates this html:

```
<ul class="post-meta">
<li>
<span class="post-meta-key">My Custom Field Title</span>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
```

I really don't want titles on the page if there's no content.  So I tried:

```
<?php
$ck = get_post_custom_keys($post_id); //Array
    foreach ($ck as $k) {
         $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array
            foreach ($cv as $c) {
                echo (' - ');
                echo ($c);
            }
    }
?>
```

Echo for $c (the custom values applied to the post) looks like this:

With no values:

- 1 - 1343633746:1 - - field_5014a45c9a2df - field_5014a48c38f9d - - field_5014a48c2cc82

With values:

- 1 - 1343603999:1 - 3 cups of eggs - field_5014a45c9a2df - field_5014a48c38f9d - 2 cups of flour - field_5014a48c2cc82

This is probably the long way to go about it.  It's showing values for things like "last edit" too, not just the two fields that I put in to test.

How I can show the Custom Fields only if they have values?  I'm writing a theme, so I do not know the names of the fields, or how many, beforehand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for empty values with `empty()`, you can check if the field starts with underscore (internal values like `_edit_last`) and skip those.

```
<?php
$ck = get_post_custom_keys($post_id); //Array
    foreach ($ck as $k) {
         if (substr ($k, 0, 1) == '_')
         {   // skip keys starting with '_'
             continue;
         }
         $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array
            foreach ($cv as $c) {
                if (empty ($c))
                {   // skip empty value
                    continue;
                }

                echo ($k . ': ' . $c . '<br/>');
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is returning the values of non-empty fields - nicely done.  Now once I figure out how to get the titles back, when the fields aren't empty, then I'll post that solution up.  Thanks! :)

Comment: If you mean the key names by titles, those are in the `$k` variable. So you could display them, maybe with `echo ($k . ': ' . $c . '<br/>');`

Answer (score 0):

Is your theme only displaying certain custom fields? Instead of testing against everything, why not just test against whether those specific custom fields are empty?

E.g.

```
$item = get_post_meta($post_id, "custom_field_1", true);
if (!empty($item)) { // if that field has something
    [...]            // display what you need to
}
```

Comment: It's not like that, unfortunately. For example, I have a site where I installed Advanced Custom Fields for the admin, who isn't me.  And if I'm writing a theme for use by any other admin besides myself, then I won't know the specific field names.  Oddly, **the_meta** is smart enough to tell the difference, which ones were added by admin, but I don't know how.